# What are the best solutions out there for SMS integration?

Tags: api, sms, bulksms

We need to send and receive large number of transactional SMS from web application, thousands of SMS per hour at certain time of the day.
Looking for a well-functioning, stable and highly reliable SMS solution. Instant delivery and 100% uptime is a must.

Though international coverage would be needed in the near future, targeted country for network coverage at the moment is India (all major cities in India).

What are the different solutions out there and how is one better than the other? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

StrikeIron can deliver SMS messages for you through your web application using an API. You can send messages to India as well as 200 other countries. The API can be set up as either SOAP or REST giving you flexibility. More at http://offers.strikeiron.com/quick-start-guide-sms-1

Or you can see how other businesses are using SMS throughout the world, in this research report about the global SMS market conducted with Portio Research at: http://offers.strikeiron.com/sms-portio-research-2